# Node js error "process with a non-zero exit code"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I developing a REST API using node js and express with MongoDB.
I have developed an endpoint to insert the user into DB and works fine. Now I have added the login function with jwt and now when I run my app and try to insert my user I receive this error:

```
an app is listening on port 3000
(node:3650) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise     rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Expected "payload" to be a plain   object.
(node:3650) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise    rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm using a node js version: 8.9.3 on mac 
Any help, please?

@ this is the code about user add:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var constants = require('../config/constants');

router.post('/',(req, res) => {
// add user --> user = { username: 'test', email: 'test@tes.com',  pwd: 'Test'}
var user = new User({
username: req.body.user.username,
email : req.body.user.email,
passhash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.user.pwd, 10)
});

user.save().then(
(newuser) => {
  var sessionToken = jwt.sign(newuser._id, constants.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: 60*60*24});
  res.json({
    user: newuser,
    message: 'success',
    sessionToken: sessionToken
  });
},
(err) => {
  res.send(500, err.message);
}
);
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is the code about login:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var constants = require('../config/constants');
var User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
User.findOne({ username: req.body.user.username}).then(
(user) => {
  if(user){
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.pwd, user.passhash, (err, matches) => {
      if (matches) {
        var sessionToken = jwt.sign(user._id, constants.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 24*60*60 });
        res.json({
          user:user,
          message: 'succesfully authed',
          sessionToken: sessionToken
        });
      }else{
        res.json({
          user: {},
          message: 'failed to auth',
          sessionToken: ''
        });
      }
    });
  }else{
    res.json({
      user: {},
      message: 'failed to auth',
      sessionToken: ''
    });
  }
},
(err) => {
  // could not find users
  res.json(err);
}
);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have tested the add user with postman and I have seen that when I receive the message posted, the user is inserted into db

Comment: you should edit your question and add some minimal code that reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes but the log doesn't say me a file with the error. What file could help to identify the problem?

Comment: since you identified that the problem happened when you added your login function, maybe the code from your login function would probably be a good start.

Comment: Ok. I have added in my original post the code.

Comment: Put a .catch after user.save and User.findOne and print out the error so we can see the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

If both API methods are declared in the same file, the problem can be because you are declaring twice same path + verb:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Pretty sure they're not the same file, since they have the `require` statements repeated. I presume they're subroutes

Comment: You are right.
Could it be because it is adding to the json response a mongoose object instead of JavaScript object:
res.json({
    user: newuser,
    message: 'success',
    sessionToken: sessionToken
  });